# $_POST variables not working with $_FILES and multipart/form-data

Tags: php, mysql, forms, post, enctype

**Problem:** Whenever I change the `enctype` on my HTML form to `multipart/form-data`, `$_POST` variables do not populate in my php script. Users upload files along with filling out a form, and the files upload to the server but the `$_POST` variables do not populate.

**Code:**

My HTML form that collects the data text/picture.

*index.php*

```
<form name="myForm" METHOD="POST" ACTION="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="text" name="text1" id="text1">
  <input type="text" name="text2" id="text2">
  <input type="file" name="filebutton" id="filebutton">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">
</form>
```

My php script that attempts to update my MySQL database, as well as upload my file on my Ubuntu server is below.

*upload.php*

```
<?php
$uploaddir = "/var/www/img/pictures/";
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['filebutton']['name']);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['filebutton']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile);
if (isset($_POST['filebutton'])) {  
    $pictureUpdate = ", PICTURE_FILEPATH = '" . $_POST['filebutton'] . "'";
} else {
    $pictureUpdate = "";
}
$connection = mysqli_connect("1.2.3.4","xxxx","xxxx","xxxx") or die("Caonnot connect to database.");
$update = "UPDATE table SET COLUMN1='" . $_POST['text1'] . "', COLUMN2='" . $_POST['text2'] . "' . $pictureUpdate . " where COLUMN3 = " . $_POST['text1'] . " ";
$update_sql = mysqli_query($connection, $update) or die("Cannot connect to mysql table. ". $update);
header("Location: " . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URL'] . "?success=1");
exit();
```

**What I've Tried:**
This is the first time doing this, so I'm kinda freestyling here because I cannot seem to get this to work.

- Changed the `enctype` to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Neither the `$_POST` or `$_FILE` data showed up in the *upload.php* file.
- Removed `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` altogether. When I do this, my `$_POST` variables work, but my file does not upload.
- Checked *php.ini* for `post_max_size`. Upon searching the internet, I've come across a couple StackOverflow topics concerning similar issues. From what I've gathered, if the file trying to be uploaded exceeds the value in `post_max_size`, then `$_POST` variables will not go through. The value in my *php.ini* file for `post_max_size` says "8M", and the test file picture being uploaded is 103 KiB.

How do I get `$_POST` data to work, as well as uploading a file from the same form?

Comment: you don't have action in your form then how's it's possible. Or you are using jquery for that

Comment: Doesn't action default to the current URI if it's not set?

Comment: blank action = current url so you want  `ACTION="upload.php"`

Comment: @John Stirling if you are asking then ok, but if you are telling then Can you see there are two files index.php and upload.php

Comment: @anantkumarsingh The upload.php could be included in index.php for all we know ;)

Comment: NO where include code is shown to me.thanks

Comment: I appreciate the comments. `action` not being set doesn't seem to be the issue; I've changed action to point to my php script, and this did not solve my problem.

Comment: you have many syntax errors and we're dealing with a file here, not a post array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to move your file stuff inside your if statement, and change `$_POST['filebutton']` to `$_FILES['filebutton']`

Whenever you do a file upload, the files get populated in the `$_FILES` global variable, and the other fields get populated in the `$_POST` global variable.

```
<?php
$uploaddir = "/var/www/img/pictures/";
if (isset($_FILES['filebutton'])) {  
    $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['filebutton']['name']);
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['filebutton']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile);
    $pictureUpdate = ", PICTURE_FILEPATH = '" . $_FILES['filebutton'] . "'";
} else {
    $pictureUpdate = "";
}
$connection = mysqli_connect("1.2.3.4","xxxx","xxxx","xxxx") or die("Caonnot connect to database.");
$update = "UPDATE table SET COLUMN1='" . $_POST['text1'] . "', COLUMN2='" . $_POST['text2'] . "' . $pictureUpdate . " where COLUMN3 = " . $_POST['text1'] . " ";
$update_sql = mysqli_query($connection, $update) or die("Cannot connect to mysql table. ". $update);
header("Location: " . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URL'] . "?success=1");
exit();
```

try this code, and see what it does for you, if this works and the other does not then that means there's more to your code we need to solve the problem.

> test.php

```
<form name="myForm" METHOD="POST" ACTION="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="text" name="text1" id="text1">
  <input type="text" name="text2" id="text2">
  <input type="file" name="filebutton" id="filebutton">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">
</form>
<xmp><?php if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') { var_dump($_FILES, $_POST); } ?></xmp>
```

> output

```
array(1) {
  ["filebutton"]=>
  array(5) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(21) "scanParser.properties"
    ["type"]=>
    string(24) "application/octet-stream"
    ["tmp_name"]=>
    string(14) "/tmp/phpRm1Ytp"
    ["error"]=>
    int(0)
    ["size"]=>
    int(264)
  }
}
array(3) {
  ["text1"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["text2"]=>
  string(1) "2"
  ["submit"]=>
  string(6) "Submit"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. However, before doing the answer above, my file was being uploaded to my server but my `$_POST` variables were not being passed. After doing the answer above, my `$_POST` variables still won't pass and now my file will not upload onto my server either.

Comment: are you sure? because prior to the code change I made your code would have blown up as soon as it tried to move the uploaded file if no file was uploaded. what happens if you put `var_dump($_FILES, $_POST);` as the very first line in `index.php`

Comment: I get this: `array(0) { } array(0) { }`.

Comment: that's after your submit the form?

Comment: Just to be clear; again, in my original code, when I take out the `enctype=multipart/form-data`, then the `POST` variables work but the file will not upload. When I add `enctype=multipart/form-data`, my file uploads but my `POST` variables won't work.

Comment: @aCarella let me tell you  that your query syntax is wrong and your code is working for me.

Comment: @anantkumarsingh Let me tell you that the query was edited so that none of my database information was posted online. That was not the focus of the question. Again, the script worked for uploading files when the encytpe was set but not for the $_POST variables, and when I got rid of the enctype the $_POST variables worked but the upload didn't.

Comment: I had the same issue, found this topic, hoped it will help. It didn't. The problem have gone by itself while I was testing the example provided by @Augwa. All I did was changing input's type from hidden to text and reloading the page. Changing it back did not reproduce the issue :) Well I'm not sure I did only that, probably the problem was in some other part of my code(not related to the form itself), or in a browser's chache!

Comment: I fought for hours to figure out why my file upload wasn't working. Yours worked wonderfully when I tested it. It wasn't until I compared our code, line by line, that I realized I was only missing an "equals" sign. (name"name"). Yes. I had a little cry. Thank you.